# Encountering 'System.OutOfMemoryException' when Reading VMs from ESXi Hypervisor

Tags: c#, powershell, esxi

I'm encountering an issue while trying to read VMs from an ESXi hypervisor using the following C# function

```
public static ReadHypervisorVmListRspn ReadHypervisorVmList(ReadHypervisorVmListRqst rqst)
{
    PowerShellClient ps = null;
    try
    {
        ps = new PowerShellClient();
        var rspn0 = ps.ExecuteScript("Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser Unrestricted");
        var rspn = new PowerShellClient.ExecuteRspn();

        // Login to the hypervisor
        var cmd = "Connect-VIServer -Server " + rqst.LoginInfo.HostUrl + " -Protocol https -User " + rqst.LoginInfo.HostUserName +
           " -Password " + rqst.LoginInfo.HostPassword;
        rspn = ps.ExecuteScript(cmd);
        if (rspn.Response != "OK")
        {
            return new ReadHypervisorVmListRspn { Response = "Unable to connect !!" };
        }

        // Fetch VM information
        cmd = "Get-Vm | Select-Object Name,PowerState,NumCPU,MemoryGB,UsedSpaceGB,ProvisionedSpaceGB,@{N='GuestFullName';E={@($_.guest.OSFullName)}},@{N='PrivateIp';E={@($_ | Get-View).Guest.Ipaddress}},@{N='MacAddress';E={($_ | Get-NetworkAdapter).MacAddress}},@{N='Uuid'; E={($_ |Get-View).config.uuid}},@{N='UpTime';E={($_ |Get-View).Summary.QuickStats.Uptimeseconds}},@{n='HardDiskSizeGB'; e={(Get-HardDisk -VM $_ | Measure-Object -Sum CapacityGB).Sum}}";
        var rspn1 = ps.ExecuteScript(cmd, true, 1);
        if (rspn1.Response.Contains("An item with the same key has already"))
            rspn1 = ps.ExecuteScript(cmd);
        if (rspn1.Response != "OK")
        {             
            // Logout from the hypervisor
            cmd = "Disconnect-VIServer -Confirm:$false;";
            var rspn5 = ps.ExecuteScript(cmd);
            return new ReadHypervisorVmListRspn { Response = rspn1.Response };
        }

        // Logout from the hypervisor
        cmd = "Disconnect-VIServer -Confirm:$false;";
        var rspn4 = ps.ExecuteScript(cmd);

        // Process fetched VM information
        var rspn3 = rspn1.Output;
        var VmInfo = Json4.GetType<List<VmInfo>>(rspn3);
        var rspn2 = new ReadHypervisorVmListRspn()
        {
            Response = "OK",
            VmInfo = VmInfo
        };

        return rspn2;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {          
        return new ReadHypervisorVmListRspn { Response = "Error" };
    }
    finally
    {
        // Clean up resources
        ps = null;
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    }
}
```

The function sometimes works successfully, but most of the time I encounter the 'System.OutOfMemoryException' error. It returns errors like:

```
18-02-2024 16:14:19 Get-NetworkAdapter  Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown. 
18-02-2024 16:14:20 Get-NetworkAdapter  Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown. 
18-02-2024 16:14:20 Get-HardDisk  Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown. 
18-02-2024 16:14:21 Get-View  Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
```

I've also tried fetching VMs in batches using a loop, but the issue persists. Is there any possible way to fix this issue?

Comment: "I've also tried fetching VMs in batches using a loop" - can you show us?